# What does the phrase "Follow that!" mean?

Tags: phrases, idioms, meaning-in-context

I've heard that nice phrase and assume it is kind of an idiom.

The possible usage I can recall:

> Follow that! I just did [insert something here].

Is that true and if so what does it mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The origin for this phrase is likely theatrical: "Hard act to follow"

Before television, people used to watch Variety Shows at theatres for entertainment.

One of the key characteristics of such a show is that as the show progresses, the acts should get better and better.

The headline act goes on *last* because they are **so good that they cannot be followed.**

So if someone cracks a great joke or tells an amazing story, the expression, "Follow that!" is an imperative or challenge to improve on the joke with an implied assertion that you cannot because it was so good.

If you are on a bill of performers and the preceding act is better than yours then there is no greater hell; for you or the audience.

Answer (score 5):

In this context, it is similar to "Top that."

Which is to say that what went on before was very good, so good, that it is unlikely that you will be able to "top" (better) it. This is said as a challenge.